# What is that `Applications` folder in Windows 10 and how to get rid of it?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-association

I found, that most programs in Windows are not links to executables anymore. They are located in unknown `Applications` folder with no path.

[image]

Is it possible to disable this feature and go back to executables links? If not, then how is it possible to know executable link from the icons of these folder?

If it is impossible, then what is the name of type of applications, which are installing this way so that I know it beforehand and never install them?

---

May be someone didn't understand the point. There is NO PATH to the folder and there is NO PATH to an application. This is the question. I can only "Explore" such an icon.

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Where did you install these "applications" from? The Windows store or from old fashioned `.exe` or `.msi` installers?

Comment: "I found, that most programs in Windows are not links to executables anymore." - What do you mean by this exactly?  The files in your screenshot are clearly executables, based on at least one of the icons, and they also have the proper context menu for an executable.  The fact they don't have a file extension is perfectly normal.  Any clarification should be done by modifying your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: @Ramhound seems like it is an UWP app that spawns from c:\users\%username%\Applications. Not sure how this path came to be, its definitely not stock windows 10, but may be UWP related.

Comment: @Ramhound the question persists: how to delete the file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97475/discussion-between-ramhound-and-dims).

Comment: Indicating you navigated to **shell:AppsFolder**, to view its contents,  would have been helpful information.  When I asked you the location of the folder, that’s when you should have shared that information, not sharing that information made several people (including myself) waste their time performing researching assuming you had an actual problem.

Comment: The first question I would have asked is "why do you want to delete it?" it's not breaking anything, and your failure to understand it is a VERY good reason not to pursue deleting it.

Answer (score 10):

**Applications** is a virtual folder, similar to **This PC**, **Control Panel**, **Network**, etc., and cannot be deleted.

For those who aren't familiar with it, it can be viewed by clicking in the **Address Bar** of **Explorer** & typing `shell:AppsFolder`

But when I right-click, most items have a few more options. Are you running under an account with Admin rights?

[image: Applications]

Comment: +1 I learned something today. Thanks for sharing. :)

Comment: @LPChip: You're welcome. For a complete list of system folder names, many (but not all) that work with the `shell` command, run this bit of PowerShell: `gp 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\*' |
select PSChildName, Name | sort Name | out-gridview`

Comment: Just for grins, here's an interactive gridview that will attempt to open the folder you select: `$folder = [ref]'dummy'; While ($folder.value) {$folder.value = (gp 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\*' |select Name | sort Name | out-gridview -PassThru);  If ($folder.value) {explorer "Shell:$($folder.value.Name)"}}`

Comment: Yes, I am admin and this is my computer and I want to erase this file along with entire folder. Microsoft's 2nd law of robotics: robot should never obey human's order even if it doesn't contradict anything :)

Comment: You delete apps via `Settings > Apps > Apps & Features`. As previously stated, the "folder" itslef is a virtual folder, an idea, a dream --- with no more substance than a shadow. You delete it every time you power down.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have any info on this “Applications” folder, never seen it. Maybe you can bring up the folders properties to allow for further investigation. But since you’re using neither the default Start Menu nor the default Explorer, you may be accessing a location that is not intended for users.

---

What you have here is a shortcut to an *app* that was installed from the Microsoft Store. ([Arduino IDE app](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBLGGH4RSD8)) For example, a link to the built-in Groove Music app looks like this:

[image: app shortcut]

If I launch this app, there’s still an `.exe` running. However, it cannot be started directly. It must be invoked using the shell.

Windows Installer can also create a special kind of shortcut, called “Advertised shortcuts”. They look very similar in that you cannot see the shortcut target. Here’s an example:

[image: advertised shortcut]

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by LPChip, they are UWP apps. They can also be called Store apps, or Universal apps.

By default they are installed into `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps`. If you open Settings and change to save new apps into drive D, for example, then new UWP apps will be in `D:\WindowsApps`.

Although you can't access any of those locations directly in Explorer, you can get into each app's directory using Task Manager:

On "Processes" tab:
[image: processes]

Or on "Details" tab:
[image: details]